# How to handle path parameter urls in HandleHttpRequest in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, path-parameter

I am calling Nifi's HandleHttpRequest Processor with dynamic Url i.e. with path parameters, for which this processor is not listening to such url.

I am looking for any solution which can help me listen path parameters to HandleHttpRequest processors

Comment: it is listening processor I think. Not sending

Comment: Ya so how can HandleHttpRequest processor listen to dynamic url such as **http://localhost:8066/master/applicationid/1/region/6**, here i am providing application id and region in path. And as this url is dynamic i am not able to set it in **Allowed path** property of the processor

Comment: Oh, I see. How about using a regular expression for the allowed path?

Comment: I had tried with regular expression before but i think it was wrong regExp as result it was not working. Now it is working with correct regular expression i tried **http://localhost:8066/master/applicationid/([0-9]*)/region/([0-9]*)**  in **Allowed path** property. Thanks @Lamanus for quick  response